# 3 point curve for every point in GN / Curvature Comb

Tags: geometry-nodes

**Bigger Picture:**
Im trying to create a Curvature Comb for surface diagnostics.
So far Im able to create a curvature Line for given point on a curve.
I want to do this for all the points on a curve and connect "loose ends" of the Lines.
The result should look something like this[image]

**Question itself:**
Im creating a 3-point circle for a point on the curve and its neighbours to find out local radius.
I want to create this circle for All the points, but I have no idea how to work with instance on points in this case. Im missing something like "For Loop".
Any ideas?

[image: curve, 3 points circe, Curve vec]

Link to the file

[image]

Comment: I think we may have to write a _Circumcircle_ group of our own.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you mean to do custom group to determine radius with math nodes, without using Circle node? And than to use that to change direction and lenght of instanced lines?

Comment: Yup . Just finished one. 2 queries, because I'm lazy.. 1. How do you want to treat end-points? Just leave them out? 2. The direction of the comb's teeth. Normal to the curve, or away from the circumcircle's center? (Not quite the same)

Comment: Would you mind sharing? I want to connect end points like on the first picture. For curves away from circle seams fine, otherwise normal to surface

Comment: [Here you go](https://blend-exchange.com/b/kzpbY6jQ/) .. this contains a group, which given 3 points a,b,c in XY,  returns the center and radius of the circle passing through all three. It could be the starting-point to an answer, which I'll write up when I can, if you like. At the moment, it's just demonstrated in another group, which draws the circumcircle of a triangle in XY.

Comment: Thank you! Its a great starting point.
It seems to work corectly only in 2D (coordinates of the points), but definitely something which I can play with.

Comment: Strictly, yes, I should have called it _CircumSphere_.  But you need only the radius, which is correct? If you needed the circle, you would have to rotate the it to the normal of the abc triangle. There's an abc triangle for every point in the curve,  (with the point at b) except the end-points.

Comment: thanks for explaining, this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142187/discussion-between-robin-betts-and-josef-ludvik-bohm).